# How to check record by record if one date is between two other dates from a second table with multiple date ranges?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am facing the following problem. I searched for hours for a similar question, but can't find an answer.

Question:

- How to check if there is a range that contains a given date using SQL?

This is more of a general question as stated in the subject, but below you can find a little context.

I want to:

- calculate if there was an active subscription for a specific user at a given date.
  Below I attach the sample tables. I want to use this later for calculations of retention/churn/reactivations etc.
- the tables are in BigQuery, so it is standard SQL question.

Given:

- Table 1: User_id and a date I want to check if there was an active subscription at this date
- Table 2: Subscription transactions with date of transaction and expiry date

Desired output:

- Table 3: Table 1 with "check" column if there is any record in the second table that it's range contains this Table1.Date

```
Table 1: User_date
|---------------------|------------------|
|      User_id        |       Date       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    2020-10-31    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    2020-11-30    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    2020-10-31    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    2020-11-30    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |    2020-10-31    |
|---------------------|------------------|


Table 2: Subscription_transactions

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|  Transaction_date   |Transaction_expiry|       User_id    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2020-10-01     |    2020-10-28    |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2020-10-29     |    2020-11-15    |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2020-10-15     |    2020-11-15    |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2020-09-29     |    2020-10-15    |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|


Table 3: Desired Output 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      User_id        |       Date       |     Is_active    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    2020-10-31    |       TRUE       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |    2020-11-30    |       FALSE      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    2020-10-31    |       TRUE       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |    2020-11-30    |       FALSE      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |    2020-10-31    |       FALSE      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select ud.*,
       exists (select 1
               from Subscription_transactions st
               where u.user_id = st.user_id and
                     u.date between st.Transaction_date and st.Transaction_expiry
              ) as is_active
from user_date ud;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
with user_date as (
select 1 user_id, '2020-10-31' date union all
select 1 user_id, '2020-11-30' date union all
select 2 user_id, '2020-10-31' date union all
select 2 user_id, '2020-11-30' date union all
select 3 user_id, '2020-10-31' date
),
Subscription_transactions as (
select '2020-10-01' Transaction_date, '2020-10-28' Transaction_expiry, 1 User_id   union all
select '2020-10-29', '2020-11-15', 1 union all
select '2020-10-15', '2020-11-15', 2 union all
select '2020-09-29', '2020-10-15', 3
)

SELECT ud.*
  , CASE WHEN st.user_id is NULL then FALSE else TRUE end
from user_date ud
left join Subscription_transactions st
 on ud.user_id = st.user_id
 and ud.date between st.Transaction_date  and st.Transaction_expiry
```